# How to add inlines based on custom queryset in Django admin?

Tags: python, django

I have two models, and they are related, but this relation is implemented in business logic, and not with database constraints, like foreign key. AFAIK Django admin offers only only one customization in that regard - [`fk_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.fk_name).

I'm seeking for a way to attach inline forms based on my own custom logic.
Is it possible somnehow? Maybe with some third-party applications, like Grappelli?